# ¿Hay manera de coercionar las clases de las columnas de un data frame a las clases de las columnas de otro data frame sin usar un for?

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame (`revs_2018`) cuyas filas quiero unir a las de otro (`revs_todo`), considerando lo siguiente:

- los nombres, cantidades y orden de las columnas son iguales
- las clases de las columnas no coinciden (las correctas son las de `revs_todo`)

```
# El número de columnas coincide en ambos data frames:
> ncol(x = revs_todo)
[1] 34
> ncol(x = revs_2018)
[1] 34

# La primera columna del data frame principal es de clase factor:
> sapply(X = revs_todo, FUN = class)[1:2]
Ruta relativa           Año 
     "factor"     "integer" 

# La primera columna del data frame secundario es de clase character:
> sapply(X = revs_2018, FUN = class)[1:2]
Ruta relativa           Año 
  "character"     "integer"
```

¿Hay manera de coercionar las clases de las columnas del data frame secundario a las clases de las columnas del data frame primario sin recurrir a un `for`, o en su defecto, unir ambos data frames manteniendo las clases del data frame principal?

Answer (score 1):

La coerción en R solo funciona para los tipos de datos básicos y los factores no lo son. De hecho, puede que el problema sea más complejo que simplemente aplicar un `as.factor()` a la columna. La pregunta que hay que hacerse ¿la nueva columna debe respetar las mismas categorías de la columna origen? ¿Qué ocurre si hay nuevas categorías?

Si simplemente buscamos convertir una columna "character" a un "factor" podemos condicionar según el tipo de dato y hacer una coerción o una conversión:

```
change_class <- function(x, y) {
  to <- class(y)
  if (to == "factor") {
    x <- factor(x)
  } else {
    x <- as(x, to)
  }
  x
}

a <- data.frame(col1 = c("3", "4"), col2 = c("a", "c"))
b <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2), col2 = factor(c("a", "b")))

f <- as.data.frame.list(mapply(FUN = change_class, a, b, SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
str(f)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1: num  3 4
 $ col2: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","c": 1 2
```